# Routing and controllers

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am new to laravel and just tried some examples. This is:

`laravel-master\app\controllers\account.php -`

```
class AccountController extends BaseController
{
    public function action_index()
    {
        echo "This is the profile page.";
    }
    public function action_login()
    {
        echo "This is the login form.";
    }
    public function action_logout()
    {
        echo "This is the logout action.";
    }
}
```

Then i added one line at - `laravel-master\app\routes.php`

```
Route::controller('account');
```

So when i will go to the main page

- myproject/account/login it should show 
  "This is the login form." .

but its showing

- `Missing argument 2 for Illuminate\Routing\Router::controller(), called in C:\Program Files\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\laravel-master\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade.php on line 177 and defined`.

Don't know what is the problem . Am i wrong somewhere ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change the name of the controller file to:

```
laravel-master\app\controllers\AccountController.php
```

Change the route definition to:

```
Route::controller('account', 'AccountController');
```

Change the controller methods to:

```
class AccountController extends BaseController
{
    public function getIndex()
    {
        echo "This is the profile page.";
    }
    public function getLogin()
    {
        echo "This is the login form.";
    }
    public function getLogout()
    {
        echo "This is the logout action.";
    }
}
```

Comment: yes it is working,after i changed the name from account.php to AccountController.php . but i didnot understand 1thing. i tried myproject/account/login its showing result page. but i tried myproject/account/Login. its showing "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel \ Exception \ NotFoundHttpException. Controller method not found." Then again i changed functon names to get_index(), get_login, get_logout(). and when i go to myproject/account/login , it shows result.So why its showing error when i change the letters to capital like- getIndex, getLogin, getLogout, get_Index, get_Login, get_logout ?

Comment: also /account/Login , /account/Index, /account/Logout do not work. but /account/login, /account/logout, /account/index working.

Comment: When using controller routing Laravel 4 allows you to use either get_login or getLogin, both accessible via account/login but *not* account/Login, account/LOGIN, etc.. In other words case sensitive

Comment: Getting this error!!!   

Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException
Class 'Base_Controller' not found
pls help

Comment: @SebinSimon check the name of the base controller class. In L4 this would be BaseController, not Base_Controller. Finally, if your controller is in a different namespace you will need to alter the name accordingly.

Comment: thanks it working now...
i followed step provided in a tutorial "codehappy by DAYLE REES...
i think codings are not in correct manner in that tutorial
can u suggest me larvel 4 good tutorial

Answer (score 1):

Not a Laravel expert, but I think your `Route::controller` is missing an argument for the destination of the route and you should use the full name of the controller class. Try

```
Route::controller('account', 'AccountController')
```

I am also not sure about the `action_`s. If I understand the [documentation on controllers](http://four.laravel.com/docs/controllers#restful-controllers) correctly, they have to be prefixed with an HTTP verb, e.g.

```
public function getIndex()
```

instead of

```
public function action_index()
```

Comment: yes as you written, i have changed those things, but now its showing - "ReflectionException . Class AccountController does not exist."